# Find the sales breakdown by product category across all of our stores

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a sales file with information such as store name, location, sales price, product name etc. The format for the file is provided below,

```
2012-01-01  09:00   San Jose    Men's Clothing  214.05  Amex
2012-01-01  09:00   Fort Worth  Women's Clothing    153.57  Visa
2012-01-01  09:00   San Diego   Music   66.08   Cash
2012-01-01  09:00   Pittsburgh  Pet Supplies    493.51  Discover
2012-01-01  09:00   Omaha   Children's Clothing 235.63  MasterCard
2012-01-01  09:00   Stockton    Men's Clothing  247.18  MasterCard
```

I would like to write a Map-reduce job to find the sales breakdown by product category across all of our stores. My code (including the Mapper and reducer) is provided below,

```
public final class P1Q1 {


    public static final class P1Q1Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, DoubleWritable> {

        private final Text word = new Text();

        public final void map(final LongWritable key, final Text value, final Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            final String line = value.toString();
            final String[] data = line.trim().split("\t");

            if (data.length == 6) {

                final String product = data[3];
                final double sales = Double.parseDouble(data[4]);

                word.set(product);
                context.write(word, new DoubleWritable(sales));
            }
        }
    }


    public static final class P1Q1Reduce extends Reducer<Text, DoubleWritable, Text, DoubleWritable> {

        public final void reduce(final Text key, final Iterable<DoubleWritable> values, final Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            double sum = 0.0;

            for (final DoubleWritable val : values) {
                sum += val.get();
            }

            context.write(key, new DoubleWritable(sum));
        }
    }


    public final static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {


        final Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        final Job job = new Job(conf, "P1Q1");
        job.setJarByClass(P1Q1.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);

        job.setMapperClass(P1Q1Map.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(P1Q1Reduce.class);
        job.setReducerClass(P1Q1Reduce.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}
```

The answer the code provides is not correct and doesn't match with the Udacity results.

Anyone knows if this the correct thought and how to do that?

Note

1. I get a completely wrong result in the output file,

   ```
   Baby    5.749180844000035E7
   Books   5.745075790999787E7
   CDs 5.741075304000156E7
   Cameras 5.7299046639999785E7
   Children's Clothing 5.762482094000117E7
   Computers   5.7315406319999576E7
   Consumer Electronics    5.745237412999948E7
   Crafts  5.7418154499999225E7
   DVDs    5.764921213999939E7
   Garden  5.7539833110000335E7
   Health and Beauty   5.748158956000019E7
   Men's Clothing  5.76212790400011E7
   Music   5.749548970000038E7
   Pet Supplies    5.71972502400004E7
   Sporting Goods  5.7599085889999546E7
   Toys    5.746347710999843E7
   Video Games 5.7513165580000155E7
   Women's Clothing    5.74344489699993E7
   ```
2. I thought if the comment out the combiner, this will be okay. I did that and doesn't change the result.

   ```
    job.setCombinerClass(P1Q1Reduce.class);
   ```
3. I provided the code and the `purchases.txt` file link is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dygPQozVOwA_uROI10mQJkCoZvE7-KD1). If anyone tries to solve the problem and successful to submit in the [Udacity](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud617/lessons/313947755/concepts/24650686840923), please, let me know.

Comment: I can provide the `purchases.txt` file - this is from the project 1 of the `Intro to Hadoop and MapReduce`  from the Udacity.

Comment: This would be a lot easier with Hive, Pig, or Spark... You are required to use MapReduce?

Comment: hi @cricket_007, great to see you again in my post.  Yes, because I'm learning the Hadoop and MapReduce now and taking a course. The course seems language independent - many students are using the Python and I choose to use the Java.

Comment: Do you know how to code it? I need to sum up the already summed up values from the individual chunks. I believe with debugging I recognized the problem but don't know how to code that.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Without the combiner, you should see the actual values from the mapper, but you should also only see one unique reducer key

Comment: Ok, You see my code and here is the instruction: https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud617/lessons/313947755/concepts/24650686840923

The `purchases.txt` file can also be downloaded from the Udacity. If you try sometime, let me know the result. I don't pay for the course, so no help from the platform.

Comment: Your output is in exponential form, so it would be 60 million units of payment, for example, but your input doesn't seem to be anywhere close to that

Comment: The file is 200 MB text file though. I upload the file in the Google drive and share here. If anyone has time to run the code and let me know the result, I will appreciate that.

Comment: From the sample input you have in the question, just run it with your code, and please edit the question to only show that as your output. Otherwise, the post is confusing.

Comment: @cricket_007 spark is very cool and easy to program compare to te hadoop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, I would say your code looks fine, and the Combiner is just an optimization, so excluding it should produce the same output as including it.

---

I wrote my own MR, and I got this output for the given input

```
Children's Clothing 235.63
Men's Clothing  461.23
Music   66.08
Pet Supplies    493.51
Women's Clothing    153.57
```

Obviously, if you have hundreds and thousands of stores, then you would get millions of currency units, as shown in your output.

Code

```
@Override
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = getConf();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, APP_NAME);
    job.setJarByClass(StoreSumRunner.class);

    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(CurrencyReducer.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
}

static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, DoubleWritable> {

    private final Text key = new Text();
    private final DoubleWritable sales = new DoubleWritable();

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable offset, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        final String line = value.toString();
        final String[] data = line.trim().split("\\s\\s+");

        if (data.length < 6) {
            System.err.printf("mapper: not enough records for %s%n", Arrays.toString(data));
            return;
        }

        key.set(data[3]);

        try {
            sales.set(Double.parseDouble(data[4]));
            context.write(key, sales);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.err.printf("mapper: invalid value format %s%n", data[4]);
        }
    }
}

static class CurrencyReducer extends Reducer<Text, DoubleWritable, Text, Text> {
    private final Text output = new Text();
    private final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text date, Iterable<DoubleWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        double sum = 0;
        for (DoubleWritable value : values) {
            sum += value.get();
        }
        output.set(df.format(sum));
        context.write(date, output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. Perhaps after finishing the course, I will have a better idea. I plan to read the book `MapReduce Design Patterns by Adam Shook` and hope that will help to write better algorithm

Comment: The main difference between yours and mine would be the `DecimalFormat` in the reducer

Comment: The algorithm is already done, and can't really be optimized. You're just grouping all stores by name and summing the number... It's easier to express in SQL, though, which is why I suggest using Spark or Hive

Comment: I don't have experience with the Spark. Thanks for your valuable suggestion though